# Oauth2 2LO between two apps in GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-oauth-java-client

I work in a project using GAE.

I have a GAE app that consume Rest services from others GAE apps (this apps uses different Google Apis with 2LO oauth2, eg: one app uses Gcalendar Api, other Gmail Api, ...). The REST apps are in Java and use GoogleCredential for consume Google Apis. All the apps are in same domain (Company is own of all projects).

I need migrate the principal GAE app (also in Java) from 2LO Oauth 1 to 2LO Oauth2.

I see this example but not is 2LO. https://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/wiki/Samples

Can I use Credential from Google-Oauth-api or GoogleCredential? Or GoogleCredential is only for Google Apis?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This [1] is the 2LO OAuth 2.0 implementation of Google OAuth you can use on App Engine and is usually refereed as the OAuth for Server to Server Applications on public documentation. This method requires of a Service Account that you can obtain on the Google Developers Console of your app. More info here [2].

[1] https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

[2] https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/app-engine

Comment: I'm waiting for pk12 file and user account. But what Scope I need to execute a call for other app?

Comment: @Guillermo81 i failed to understand your use case, I think what you want is described in [this article](http://ikaisays.com/2011/05/26/setting-up-an-oauth-provider-on-google-app-engine/)